# Converts any String input to UpperCase without using .toUpperCase();

Tags: java

I got an assignment to code a programme that converts any String input to UpperCase as output. But I can not use .toUpperCase(); method. Can I get a guideline how to start it? Thank you.

Comment: We're not here to do your assignments for you

Comment: I think you can consider the ASCII. And by the way, we will not do your homework.

Comment: Strings are an array of characters. Characters are stored as an integer representation of the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/). The distance from a lowercase letter to the same uppercase letter is the same (32 characters). Uppercase letter = ((char) (int) lowercase letter - 32).

Comment: You can look inside the toUppercase method and see how they do it there

Comment: You can search "upper case java without touppercase" in google.

Comment: @nbokmans Actually, characters are stored as unicode code points in the basic multilingual plane. It happens to correspond with ASCII in the first 128 places and with ISO-8859-1 in the first 256 places.

Comment: @Henry didn't know about it that in-depth, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @cricket_007 honestly, I have no idea how to start it. I guess you misunderstood me. I'm not asking you guys to do my assignment for me. I'm just asking for a guideline. Thank you.

Comment: Giving you a guideline is practically the same thing. It defeats the purpose of developing your problem solving skills

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, post what you have tried so far in your question.

As for getting started with your assignment,

1. Capture the user's input and store it in a variable say `inputString`.
2. You can get an array of characters that make up `inputString` using `inputString.getCharAt(index)`.
3. Use a new empty `StringBuffer` for your output.
4. Use a `for` loop to iterate the `inputString`.
5. Then check if each character is a lower case alphabet.
6. If step 4 is true, then append the appropriate upper case letter for that alphabet to the StringBuffer you created in step 3.
7. After the end of the loop, return `StringBuffer.toString()` as the output.

For step 6, look at the ascii/unicode numbers for each alphabet and you can get to know what is the equivalent upper case value for each lower case alphabet.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: first, up-vote. you may need to describe how to upper case a `char` in detail, e.g: using [Character#toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-).

Answer (score 0):

Not like other answer describe your assignment **how** to do? I break your assignment into **what** you will need to do into a todo task list? and then you can done it by your self.

- how to extract a `char[]` array from a `String`?
- how to operate on an array?
- how to upper case a `char`?
- how to upper case all of `char`s in an array?
- how to create a `String` from a `char[]` array?

when you done these tasks above, you eventually complete your homework. and each task you can think about **how** to do it for a while. and then google.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperCase{
   public static void main(String[] htz) {
       Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Input :");
       String res=sr.nextLine();
       String res1=res.toLowerCase();
       char[] res2=res1.toCharArray();
       for(int i=0; i<res2.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<res2.length; j++){
               if('a' <= res2[i] && res2[i] <= 'z'){
                   res2[i]+='A'-'a';
                   System.out.print(res2[i]);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay (except for the typo), this works for the lower case letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block of Unicode. For a quality answer, it should include some explanation, particularly as it relates to that limitation.